# Singleton class on main thread - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, singleton

My question maybe is silly but i cannot understand this. I create a singleton class using this code.

```
+ (GameRequestHandler *) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static GameRequestHandler *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[GameRequestHandler alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}
```

When i call methods from this singleton object, are they called on the main thread or in a background thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The methods are called on the thread you invoke them from.

`dispatch_once` just ensures that the block passed to it is only executed once in the lifetime of the application.  I don't think it uses threads and if it does, that is an implementation detail you don't need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the call on main thread use this;

```
dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    shared = [[GameRequestHandler alloc] init];
        });
    });
```